# Symfony inject service Class without call her constructor

Tags: php, symfony, service

Hi i want to inject a service Class without call her constructor, be cose i havent yet the argument to pass to this constructor class injected.

Exemple:

```
services:
your.service.name:
    class:  AppBundle\Services\YourClassName
    arguments:  ['@doctrine.services.paginator']

doctrine.services.paginator:
  class: Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator
  public: false
```

return error

> Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   ... and at least 1 expected

Comment: Why are you wanting to inject the `Paginator` without calling the constructor? I have a feeling your trying to go about something the wrong way.

Comment: can i do "new Paginator()" inside service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to instantiate a class without using the constructor,
PHP documentation says :

> PHP 5 allows developers to declare constructor methods for classes. Classes which have a constructor method call this method on each newly-created object, so it is suitable for any initialization that the object may need before it is used.

[PHP constructor documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

If you want to use the paginator without injecting dependencies, you could follow the doctrine documentation :

[Doctrine paginator documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html)

Basically you insert use statement in your repository.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;
```

And then use an object of the Paginator Class with your query :

```
$qb = $this->CreateQueryBuilder('u');
// ... build your query here...
$qb->getQuery();
$paginator = new Paginator($qb, false);
$count = count($paginator);
return array($paginator, $count); // Process the results in your controller
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You can use setter injection, which is optional, and not really recommended, but I won't go deep about that.

Example:

```
<?php

class YourClassName 
{
    private $paginator;

    public function setPaginator(PaginatorInterface $paginator)
    {
        $this->paginator = $paginator;
    }

    public function getPaginator()
    {
        if ($this->paginator instanceof PaginatorInterface) {
            return $this->paginator;
        }

        throw new \RuntimeException('Paginator is not defined');
    }
}
```

Then you can inject your service without specifying paginator as an argument:

```
services:
    your.service.name:
        class:  AppBundle\Services\YourClassName
```

and instead inject it in a runtime:

```
$this->get('your.service.name')->setPaginator($paginator);
```

In case, if you need inject paginator also with container, you can use `calls` argument with service, [more in docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/calls.html).

If you need to get new instance each time you get service from container, you can use `shared` argument, [more in docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/shared.html).